# Redirect to HTTPS www - Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns, webserver

I have a site

`www.boring.com`

I need to make sure that these 3 cases :

- http://boring.com
- https://boring.com
- http://www.boring.com

will to redirect to

- https://www.boring.com

I'm using Nginx in Laravel 5 on Ubuntu hosted on Digital Ocean.

---

This is what I set in Digital Ocean

[image]

---

## Result

RIght now, only one seem to work

http://www.boring.com

redirect to

https://www.boring.com

---

These 2 are not

http://boring.com

> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

https://boring.com

> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Did I do anything wrong on Digital Occean ?

Where can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you set any `A` records for ne non-www versions?

Comment: @tkausl : Is this considering I did it ? https://i.imgur.com/JbVUj5q.png

Comment: This record applys to all subdomains but not to the domain itself.

Comment: You quote your `.htaccess` file which is an Apache configuration file. Nginx does not use it.

Comment: @RichardSmith I removed it I didn't know.

Comment: @tkausl Can you answer the peace that I missed ?

Comment: You're missing an `A` record for `bunlongheng.com` (without the `*.` at the beginning)

Comment: Isn't it that is what I have for the second row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CloudFlare. So all SSL and subdomain redirections related not only to your server (Nginx) configuration but also to CloudFlare settings.

All you need to do is to check out whether your domain name is listed in CloudFlare's DNS settings (see DNS tab). "www" subdomain is listed there, but the direct domain name was missing.